# Communication between N node.js processes

Tags: node.js

So I have an app written in node.js. I run many instances of this app in the same server and specify their "id" with an argument when starting the app, like:

```
node app.js <ID>
```

I would like this app to receive messages from any other instance, and send messages to any other instance aswell.
So each instance is "listening" messages on channel "`app<ID>`" and can send messages to any channel from "`app1`" to "`appN`".
What is the best way to achieve this? A redis server and it's pubsub system? ZeroMQ or NSQ or similar solutions? Can socket.io be used?

Comment: You're going to get different answers based on opinions, which makes this question a bit off-topic for StackOverflow. For example my opinion would be to use Redis pubsub.

Comment: You should post specific requirements (are messages transient or should delivery be guaranteed? what needs to happen if an app with a particular id isn't running? etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For inter-process communication (IPC), you might consider [node-ipc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ipc) which is exactly what you're describing in your question. It also has the added bonus to allow communication across different hosts (if you ever expand your app on multiple servers).

Your app should have a **master** acting as central hub, then **auxiliaries** connecting to it.

#### Master

```
const ipc=require('node-ipc');

ipc.config.id    = 'world';
ipc.config.retry = 1500;

ipc.serve(function() {
  ipc.server.on('app.event', function(data, socket) {
    // broadcast to all clients
    ipc.server.broadcast('app.event', data);
  });
);

ipc.server.start();
```

#### Auxiliary-ies

```
const ipc=require('node-ipc');
const EventEmitter = require('events');

// export our event emitter
const events = module.exports = new EventEmitter();

ipc.config.id    = 'client' + CID;  // CID = from args
ipc.config.retry = 1500;

ipc.connectTo('world', function() {
  const _emit = events.emit;  // preserve old emit function

  ipc.of.world.on('connect', function() {
    ipc.log('## connected to world ##', ipc.config.delay);

    // override event emitter's emit function
    events.emit = function (event, data) {
      ipc.of.world.emit('app.event', {
        id: ipc.config.id,
        event: event,
        data: data
      });
    };
  });

  ipc.of.world.on('disconnect', function() {
    ipc.log('disconnected from world');

    // can't emit anymore, so just noop
    events.emit = function () {};
  });

  ipc.of.world.on('kill.connection', function(data) {
    ipc.log('world requested kill.connection');
    ipc.disconnect('world');
  });

  ipc.of.world.on('app.event', function(data) {
    ipc.log('got a message from world : ', data);

    if (data.id !== ipc.config.id) {
      // fire events listeners
      _emit.call(events, data.event, data.data); 
    }
  });

});
```

**Note**: The **master** should also connect to itself to receive events from other auxiliaries! If the server code and client code are in their respective modules, then you only need to require the master from your master process and auxiliary from every processes (even master).

Comment: It's a good solution, even though I finally ended up using redis pubsub for the sake of simplicity